# JavaFX not working

Tags: 18.04, java, javafx

I need to run a software built using Java. I downloaded the JRE and JDK, but the software needs to use JavaFX. As I understand it, JavaFX was decoupled from the main packages in more recent Linux releases, so I went and downloaded OpenJFX, but the program still insists that there is no JFX. Any ideas?

I am running Bionic Beaver, with all of the above packages downloaded from the official Canonical releases.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, post your Ubuntu release/version, what exactly have you downloaded and from where and how have you installed it.